# Calculating percentages of total at equal intervals in a data set in R

Tags: r, percentage, calculated-columns

I am working on a dataset that contains the total for each FMCG category and its distribution of sales by each major channel as indicated in the columns. The extract is as below

```
CTY  totsal MTsal   GTsal   Othsal  totsal  MTsal   GTsal   Othsal
     food   food    food    food    deo      deo    deo      deo
Arg  47313  19620   15052   12641   178      113    41       24
Aus  143140 85172   4634    53334   459      438    5        16
Bel  125399 82966   7818    34614   424      229    5        190
```

In my output data set I want to to calculate shares of the total category group which is in every 4th column e.g. totsal food and totsal deo. SO the shares for these must be 1 and the shares for the channels which add up to to the total must be their respective values. The example output I am looking at is:

```
CTY totshar MTshar  GTshar  Othshar totshar MTshar  GTshar  Othshar
    food    food    food    food    deo      deo    deo      deo
Arg  1      0.4     0.3     0.3     1.0      0.6    0.2      0.1
Aus  1      0.6     0.0     0.4     1.0      1.0    0.0      0.0
Bel  1      0.7     0.1     0.3     1.0      0.5    0.0      0.4
```

The above example is an extract and I need to incorporate flexibility to include as many categories and countries I can.

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your data frame? (just `dput(head(df))`)

Comment: Hi not sure what you mean. The example I have shown is an excerpt. Here there are 8 columns in which the 1st is the total for column no. 2 3 4 and 5th is the total for column 6 7 8 . This progression continues for the whole data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.
First I copied&pasted your data:

```
d <- read.table("clipboard",header=T)
d
   CTY totsal MTsal GTsal Othsal totsal.1 MTsal.1 GTsal.1 Othsal.1
1 <NA>   food  food  food   food      deo     deo     deo      deo
2  Arg  47313 19620 15052  12641      178     113      41       24
3  Aus 143140 85172  4634  53334      459     438       5       16
4  Bel 125399 82966  7818  34614      424     229       5      190
```

Then I transformed the numbers to a numeric matrix

```
m <- data.frame(d[-1, -1])
m <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
m
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
2  47313 19620 15052 12641  178  113   41   24
3 143140 85172  4634 53334  459  438    5   16
4 125399 82966  7818 34614  424  229    5  190
```

I searched for the total columns using `grep`, and created an index `gr` for the column groups. Of note, the `total` column must always the first column of the group. The total number of group values can vary.

```
gr_total <- grep("tot", colnames(d)[-1])
gr <- sort(rep(gr_total, 4))
```

I used `sapply` to calculate the percentage per group and transform the result using the `matrix`funtion. The sapply function "loops" through all groups found by the `grep` search. Within the `function(x, y, z)` it subsets all columns belonging to the group. Here for the first `m[, gr == gr_total[1]]`. Because R is optimized for vectorized processes you can divide a vector/matrix by a vector. Try `m[, gr == gr_total[1]]/m[ , gr_total[1]]`. For the `matrix()` function please see `?matrix` and check the `sapply` output.

```
matrix(sapply(gr_total, function(x, y, z)  z[, y==x]/z[, x], gr, m), nrow(m), ncol(m), byrow = FALSE)
     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4] [,5]      [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,]    1 0.4146852 0.31813666 0.2671782    1 0.6348315 0.23033708 0.13483146
[2,]    1 0.5950258 0.03237390 0.3726003    1 0.9542484 0.01089325 0.03485839
[3,]    1 0.6616161 0.06234499 0.2760309    1 0.5400943 0.01179245 0.44811321
```

You can use the `round` function to round for one digit. Assuming you saved the result in `m1` use `round(m1, 1)`.
Colnames can be replaced by `colnames(m1) <- colnames(d)[-1]`. To add columns and rows see `rbind` and `cbind`.

Comment: Works perfect. Could you explain the last sapply and matrix code a bit in detail? Also I donot get the column names as the original data set. I get them as V1 V2 etc, is there a way to get them back or replace these V1 V2 with the original column names?